# How can I connect to polygon.io web socket via Alpaca?

Tags: python, polygon, alpaca

Whenever I try to use the command:

`wscat -c wss://alpaca.socket.polygon.io/stocks`

I get the following error message displayed:

`error: self-signed certificate`

I'm using PyCharm on my 2022 MacBook Air. Can anyone help here?

- tried this what I found online:

  `npm config set strict-ssl=false`

  did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Alpaca does not support Polygon anymore:

- https://forum.alpaca.markets/t/we-are-losing-polygon-data/4542/10
- https://alpaca.markets/learn/the-top-3-differences-between-polygon-and-alpaca-data-plans/
- https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-references/market-data-api/stock-pricing-data/realtime/